# Read JSON from rest API as is with Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, rest, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get Azure Data Factory to read my REST API and put it in SQL Server. The source is a REST API and the sink is a SQL Server table.

I tried to do something like:

```
"translator": {
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "schemaMapping": {
        "$": "json"
    },
    "collectionReference": "$.tickets"
}
```

The source looks like:

```
{ "tickets": [ {... }, {...} ] }
```

Because of the poor mapping capabilities I'm choosing this path. I'll then split the data with a query. Preferbly I'd like to store each object inside tickets as a row with JSON of that object.

In short, how can I get the JSON output from the RestSource to a SqlSink single column text/nvarchar(max) column?

Comment: I just save the entire document into a VARCHAR(MAX) field then use JSON functions inside T-SQL to shred it out. What's the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: How do I get the actual json to a VARCHAR(MAX) field? DF keeps trying to parse it.

Comment: Before we get to the VARCHAR(MAX) thing, whata problem are you having? Error or incorrect data? TBH. I've only ever done this via Stream Analytics. I don't have access to ADF to play right now, but one way to do  is to use the web Activity task, call the API and use the output to insert into a table...in theory

Comment: Well, we're trying to get the data to SQL server without providing a static schema. This is because the data loading team is different from the team that uses the data. When you leave the schema mapping empty, ADF tries to map it automatically, which works for flat JSON, where you only have keys in the first level. When you get to nested objects or arrays, it ignores those. So my solution would be to put the whole json in one column and query it from there.

Comment: In SQL, create a stored proc that takes a VARCHAR(MAX) parameter and inserts that into your table. In ADF, drop on a Web task. Put your REST call into it and test. Now add a Stored Procedure Task and call your stored proc. Import the parameter. In the Value field, set dynamic content and enter this `@string(activity('Call REST').output)` (where Call REST is the name of your Web task). That will call the API once and insert it. If you need to do it repeatedly you'll need to explain further. If this works you can write it up as an answer (or I will)

Comment: Well, I can check that out and that'll probably work, however then I can't use the RestSource's pagination support. Would be better for me if CopyData activity had an option somehow to copy the native as-is json.

Comment: Is this a clue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#export-json-response-as-is _You can use this REST connector to export REST API JSON response as-is to various file-based stores. To achieve such schema-agnostic copy, skip the "structure" (also called schema) section in dataset and schema mapping in copy activity._

Comment: SQL Server is not a file-based store; It seems to work if you store the data in a blob store first, then extract the structure with 'Get metadata' activity and store it in sql server afterwards.

Comment: The main point was that link is it implied you could treat the JSON as just a big flat "schema agnostic" string. (and then I assume write that in a database)

Comment: Yes, that was my assumption aswell, but that doesn't seem to work if you write to a non-filebased store like SQL Server. Then it always tries to interpret the schema and cannot store the whole json in a nvarchar(max), varchar(max) or text field.

Comment: Oh I see. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the same issue by modifying mapping manually.
ADF anyway tries to parse json, but from the Advanced mode you can edit json paths. Ex., this is the original schema parsed automatically by ADF
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy0cD.jpg
Once opened in Advanced mode it will show full paths by adding indexes of the elements, something similar to $tickets[0][] etc
Try to delete all other columns and keep the only one $tickets (the highest level one), in my case it was $value https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnAzC.jpg. As the result the entire json will be written into the destination column.

If there are pagination rules in place, each page will be written as a single row.